# Import javascript var in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am new to Angular CLI and try to import a javascript file to get more familiar with Angular CLI:

```
// src/utils.js
var text = "TEST";
var util = {
    sayHello: function(name) {
            console.log( "Hello, " + name );

         }
}
```

For this file I have created a typing file:

```
// src/utils.d.ts
declare module 'utils'; 
export var util: any;
declare var text: any;
```

Now I want to use the javascript file in main.ts:

```
// src/main.ts
// ...
import * as util from 'utils';

console.log('TEXT: ', util.text);
util.sayHello("Bob");
// ...
```

This compiles successfully, but throws the following runtime error:

src/main.ts(12,6): error TS2339: Property 'sayHello' does not exist on type 'typeof

Did I miss something or is there something wrong in my code? I use the following versions:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 6.14.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `allowJs : true`  in tsconfig file ?

Comment: in your `util.js` have you tried adding `export default` ?

Comment: It works when I add the "export" keyword to each var in util.js. Then I can access the text-var and can call util.util.sayHello("Bob") in main.ts. But there should be a way to use the js-script in main.ts without modifying the js-file, shouldn't it? If not, this would mean I have to add "export" to each var of a 3rd-party js-lib?